# Single quote replacement, handling of null integers in pandas/python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, replace, pandas, nan

New to Pandas/Python and I'm having to write some kludgy code. I would appreciate any input on how you would do this and speed it up (I'll be doing this for gigabytes of data).

So, I'm using pandas/python for some ETL work. Row-wise calculations are performed so I need them as numeric types within the process (left this part out). I need to output some of the fields as an array and get rid of the single quotes, nan's, and ".0"'s.

First question, is there a way to vectorize these if else statements ala `ifelse` in `R`? Second, surely there is a better way to remove the ".0". There seems to be major issues with out pandas/numpy handles nulls in numeric types.

Finally, the `.replace` does not seem to work on the DataFrame for single quotes. Am I missing something? Here's the sample code, please let me know if you have any questions about it:

```
import pandas as pd

# have some nulls and need it in integers
d = {'one' : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],'two' : [4.0, 3.0, NaN, 1.0]}
dat = pd.DataFrame(d)

# make functions to get rid of the ".0" and necessarily converting to strings
def removeforval(val):
    if str(val)[-2:] == ".0":
        val = str(val)[:len(str(val))-2]
    else:
        val = str(val)
    return val
def removeforcol(col):
    col = col.apply(removeforval)
    return col
dat = dat.apply(removeforcol,axis=0)
# remove the nan's
dat = dat.replace('nan','')

# need some fields in arrays on a postgres database
quoted  = ['{' + str(tuple(x))[1:-1] + '}'  for x in dat.to_records(index=False)]
print "Before single quote removal"
print quoted

# try to replace single quotes using DataFrame's replace
quoted_df = pd.DataFrame(quoted).replace('\'','')
quoted_df = quoted_df.replace('\'','')
print "DataFrame does not seem to work"
print quoted_df

# use a loop
for item in range(len(quoted)):
    quoted[item] = quoted[item].replace('\'','')
print "This Works"
print quoted
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you show what you want your output to be?

Comment: [{4,1},{2,3},{3,},{4,1}] just like the last output

Comment: I misspoke it's a list like this ['{1, 4}', '{2, 3}', '{3, }', '{4, 1}']

Comment: ok, the ``{`` are also really odd, that's a dictionary (and not a tuple reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand that this is very odd to make a string exactly like this. This is not valid python at all. What are you doing with this? Why are you stringifying it?

revised

```
In [144]: list([ "{%s , %s}" % tup[1:] for tup in df.replace(np.nan,0).astype(int).replace(0,'').itertuples() ])
Out[144]: ['{1 , 4}', '{2 , 3}', '{3 , }', '{4 , 1}']
```

Comment: My faith in Python is restored. 2 slight deviations. I actually don't know how many columns there are before the script runs. I'll just feed the needed string into your code. Also, I have many other fields in the overall DataFrame. 

Right now I'm sub-setting from a list of columnnames determined by some other logic. I'm still wondering if there is a way to vectorize that logic. I.e., if columnname in list then do this, else do this, without that construct. The entire point of this is to save and load to postgres via psql COPY, and this is the format for SQL arrays.

Comment: you are much better off just using ``df.to_sql()`` (renamed in forthcoming 0.12), see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#sql-queries